# C++ - Static polymorphism vs Runtime polymorphism vs Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, static, static-polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

I learned the difference between static and run-time polymorphism and since then I've been reading a lot of stuff on it.
Plus, since I found out that implementing a static polymorphic interface (in a manner that a class can use an object with the base class definition without knowing what "derived" class the object was instantiated with).

So I ran a little test to compare these different implementations.

Here is the code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

class BaseLambda
{
    public:
        double run(double param){return m_func(param);};
    protected:
        BaseLambda(std::function<double(double)> func) : m_func(func) {  };
        std::function<double(double)> m_func;
};

class DerivedLambda : public BaseLambda
{
    public:
        DerivedLambda() : BaseLambda([](double param){return DerivedLambda::runImpl(param);}) {  };
    private:
        static double runImpl(double param) {return (param * param) / 2.5;};
};

class BaseVirtual
{
    public:
        double run(double param){return runImpl(param);};
    protected:
        virtual double runImpl(double param) = 0;
};

class DerivedVirtual : public BaseVirtual
{
    protected:
        double runImpl(double param) {return (param * param) / 2.5;};
};


template<class C> class BaseTemplate
{
    public:
        double run(double param){return static_cast<C*>(this)->runImpl(param);};
};

class DerivedTemplate : public BaseTemplate<DerivedTemplate>
{
    public:
        double runImpl(double param) {return (param * param) / 2.5;};
};


int main()
{
    std::clock_t  c_start = std::clock();

    std::unique_ptr<BaseVirtual> baseVirtual = std::make_unique<DerivedVirtual>();
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; ++i) {
        auto var = baseVirtual->run(10.6);
    }
    baseVirtual.reset(nullptr);

    std::clock_t  c_end = std::clock();

    std::cout << "Execution time with virtual : "
        << 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ms" << std::endl;


    c_start = std::clock();

    std::unique_ptr<BaseLambda> baseLambda = std::make_unique<DerivedLambda>();
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; ++i) {
        auto var = baseLambda->run(10.6);
    }
    baseLambda.reset(nullptr);

    c_end = std::clock();

    std::cout << "Execution time with lambda : "
        << 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ms" << std::endl;


    std::unique_ptr<BaseTemplate<DerivedTemplate>> baseTemplate = std::make_unique<DerivedTemplate>();
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; ++i) {
        auto var = baseTemplate->run(10.6);
    }
    baseTemplate.reset(nullptr);

    c_end = std::clock();

    std::cout << "Execution time with template : "
        << 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

The thing is, when I ran this, the virtual implementation is the fastest while static polymorphism is supposed to be faster.
Here is an execution result example:

Execution time with virtual: 53 ms
 Execution time with lambda: 94 ms
 Execution time with template: 162 ms

I'm guessing that it is because of some compiler optimization. I compile with gcc 6.3.0.

The my question is: why the template implementation the slowest? Is it really because of compiler's optimization, and if it is, what are they and how can I change my test to have the "real" running time? And if not, what have I done wrong?

Comment: err, you forget to take `c_start` at the start?

Comment: Certainly one `c_start = std::clock();` is missing

Comment: `std::function<double(double)>` is not a lambda, it uses type erasure (and does virtual call or similar).

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<BaseLambda> baseLambda = std::make_unique<DerivedLambda>();` introduces UB as `BaseLambda` is not `virtual`.

Comment: @Jarod42 how do you mean "BaseLambda is not virtual"? Only member functions can be virtual. Are you referring to `~BaseLambda` ? That is likely not relevant for performance.

Comment: Missing one character indeed: `~BaseLambda`; destructor is not virtual. With **U**ndefined **B**ehavior, the code becomes meaningless.

Comment: With fixed and factorized code, I got those [results](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64252d2179965a94). template (1.4), std::function(8.6), virtual(12.3)

Comment: Trying to benchmark unoptimised code?